# django templates accessing a dict value based on key

Tags: django, templates, for-loop, nested

in my views.py i obtain 5 dicts, which all are something like {date:value}
all 5 dicts have the same length and in my template i want to obtain some urls based on these dicts, with the common field being the date - as you would do in an sql query when joining 5 tables based on a common column

in python you would do something like:

```
for key, value in loc.items():
    print key, loc[key], ctg[key], sctg[key], title[key], id[key]
```

but in django templates all i could come up with is this:

```
{% for lock, locv in loc.items %}
    {% for ctgk, ctgv in ctg.items %}
        {% for subctgk, subctgv in subctg.items %}
            {% for titlek, titlev in titlu.items %}
                {% for idk, idv in id.items %}

                          {% ifequal lock ctgk %}
                            {% ifequal ctgk subctgk %}
                                {% ifequal subctgk titlek %}
                                    {% ifequal titlek idk %}

                                    <br />{{ lock|date:"d b H:i" }} - {{ locv }} - {{ ctgv }} - {{ subctgv }} - {{ titlev }} - {{idv }}
                                     .... {% endifequals & endfors %}
```

which of course is ugly and takes a lot of time to be rendered

right now i am looking into building a custom tag, but i was wondering if you guys have any feedback on this topic?

Comment: Using a custom tag seems better for me. Maybe Jinja2 can help you, but I'm not sure about that...

Comment: i created a custom tag which does a dict.get(key) which is exactly what i need in my template!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you need to use something other than aligned dicts. How about a dict of a small class, which contains the things you want:

```
class MyThing:
  def __init__(self, loc, ctg, sctg, title, id):
    self.loc = loc
    self.ctg = ctg
    self.sctg = sctg
    self.title = title
    self.id = id
```

Would that make your template code a bit less painful? (Apologies if I've misunderstood the problem - I'm having a hard time following your nested `if`s!).

Comment: to understand the ifs think about 5 dicts with these values: {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'x', 6: 'aa'}

and the ifs allow to print out dict1[1] dict2[1] .. dict5[1]
and dict1[2] dict2[2] .. dict5[2], etc

Comment: thanks for the idea but i created a custom tag which makes wonders :)

Answer (score 0):

Django templates should try to resolve variables with dot as a dictionary lookup (if varaible is an dictionary). So `ctg.key` equals to `ctg[key]`. Did you try this:

```
{% for key, value in loc.items %}
  {{ key|date:"d b H:i" }} - {{ value }} - {{ ctg.key }} - {{ subctg.key }} - {{ title.key }} - {{ id.key }}
```

Comment: nope it doesnt work ... best thing is to create a tag or a filter, depending on your needs ... i created a tag, but right now i figured out that a filter would have been better